# accumulating functions and closures in R

Tags: r, closures

I am constructing an approximating function recursively (adaboost). I would like to create the resulting learning function along the way (not to apply the approximation directly to my test data but keep the function that leads to it)

unfortunately, it seems that R updates the value to which a variable name refers to long after it is used.

```
#defined in plyr as well
id <- function(x) {x}

#my first classifier 
modelprevious <- function(inputx, k) { k(0)}

#one step of my superb model
modelf <- function(x) 2*x #for instance

#I update my classifier
modelCurrent <- function(inputx, k) 
                 { modelprevious(inputx, function(res) {k(res + modelf(inputx))})}

#it works
modelCurrent(2,id) #4

#Problem
modelf <- function(x) 3*x
modelCurrent(2,id) #6 WTF !!
```

The same function with the same argument return something different, which is quite annoying !

So how is it possible to capture the **value** represented by modelf so that the resulting function only depends on its argument at the time of the binding, and not of some global state ?

---

Given that problem I dont see how one can do a recursive function building in R if one can not touch local variable, apart going through ugly hacks of quote/parse

Comment: I'm baffled as to why you're confused. `modelCurrent` (watch the typo there, btw) depends upon `modelf`. You changed the definition of `modelf`...

Comment: I would like the value of modelf to be captured, and not be subject to spooky action at a distance.

Comment: There is absolutely no spooky action at a distance happening here. You _explicitly_ altered the definition of `modelCurrent`.

Comment: I have to use a name for my previous accumulated function. now if I want to update my previous classifier with the new classifier and recurse, I have to reuse that name, say "previousClassifier". How can I do recursion if I can not touch the names used previously ?

Comment: when you reuse a variable name, say x, to store a number, do you expect all your *previous* variables that used x to be computed to change as well ?

Comment: If those variables hold functions, then _yes_, I absolutely do. Or actually, this will happen due to lexical scoping even if you replaced it with a simple scalar. I frankly don't understand (a) what you're trying to do and (b) why this behavior is in any way strange.

Comment: Maybe this will help: when you define the function `modelCurrent`, nothing is actually evaluated. Each symbol in the function definition is only evaluated when it's actually needed. So the first time `modelf(inputx)` is needed, it finds one definition, the second time, you've redefined it.

Comment: A function or a number should be on equal footing as bindings are concerned. otherwise just doing the same operation, in a function would change the behaviour of your program. what a nightmare !

Comment: Yes, _and you explicitly changed the binding of `modelf`_!

Comment: look. x <- 0, a <- x + 2, x <- 2, do you expect a to be == 2. that is why there are closures, etc..

Comment: That's completely different. As I said, everything inside a _function_ is evaluated _only_ when it's called. This behavior will _only_ arise inside functions.

Comment: well allow me to be baffled as to why that is sensible that number and functions follow different rules.

Comment: Look yourself: `x <- 1; f <- function() {print(x)}; f(); x <- 2; f()`

Comment: This is called lazy evaluation (in conjunction with lexical scoping) and it is by no means a strange language feature. Maybe [this](http://cran.us.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Scope) will help some.

Comment: there are ways to freeze the definition of `modelf` that is used inside your `modelCurrent` function. One of them is to use a package; the namespace mechanism ensures that modelf from that package will have priority over user-overwrites for internal use. Similarly, you can place `modelf` in a specific environment, and make sure you look there first inside `modelCurrent`. That's the way it works; I can just as easily define `print <- invisible` and screw up my R session for most visible purposes, but that's a powerful feature.

Answer (score 10):

You need a factory:

```
modelCurrent = function(mf){
  return(function(inputx,k){
    modelprevious(
      inputx,
      function(res){
        k(res+mf(inputx))
      } # function(res)
      ) # modelprevious
  } # inner function
         ) # return
} # top function
```

Now you use the factory to create models with the `modelf` function that you want it to use:

```
> modelf <- function(x) 2*x
> m1 = modelCurrent(modelf)
> m1(2,id)
[1] 4
> modelf <- function(x) 3*x
> m1(2,id) # no change.
[1] 4
```

You can always make them on an ad-hoc basis:

```
> modelCurrent(modelf)(2,id)
[1] 6
```

and there you can see the factory created a function using the current definition of `modelf`, so it multiplied by three.

There's one last ginormous WTF!?! that will hit you. Watch carefully:

```
> modelf <- function(x) 2*x
> m1 = modelCurrent(modelf)
> m1(2,id)
[1] 4
>
> m1 = modelCurrent(modelf) # create a function using the 2* modelf
> modelf <- function(x) 3*x # change modelf...
> m1(2,id) # WTF?!
[1] 6
```

This is because when the factory is called, `mf` isn't evaluated - that's because the inner function isn't called, and `mf` isn't used until the inner function is called.

The trick is to force evaluation of the `mf` in the outer function, typically using `force`:

```
modelCurrent = function(mf){
  force(mf)
  return(function(inputx,k){
    modelprevious(
      inputx,
      function(res){
        k(res+mf(inputx))
      } # function(res)
      ) # modelprevious
  } # inner function
         ) # return
} # top function
```

This has lead me to premature baldness, because if you forget this and think there's some odd bug going on, and then try sticking `print(mf)` in place to see what's going on, you'll be evaluating `mf` and thus getting the behaviour you wanted. By inspecting the data, you changed it! A Heisenbug!

Comment: Thank you for laying this down. I was heading there but unsure. the force, as it is implemented, it definitely wrong. lazyness as a feature is interesting, but that is a faulty implementation of it.

Comment: regarding the recursion, one last piece is missing here, in that the resulting function will be tied to the current definition of modelprevious, which will be troublesome as we recurse and change is binding. therefore, an extra factory, or local environment is necessary to explicitely capture the current definition of modelprevious.

Comment: one way to do this is apparently to add after return a local environment   return(
    local({
    cmodelprevious <- modelprevious
    function(inputx,k){
      cmodelprevious(
      inputx,
      function(res){
        k(res+mf(inputx))
      } # function(res)
    ) # modelprevious
  } # inner function
  }) # local

Comment: so that the returned function will not look up the definition in the environment prevailing when you call it, but when it was defined. I think that is the big takeaway of all this : you have to define closure yourself and name binding changes the meaning of your program (no 'referential transparency')

Comment: from what I see, we only use the function to create an environment. i tend to think that it might be better then to use the "local" keyword, which clearly express the intent, over a factory

Comment: Whatever. I'm curious as to what programming world you come at R from - clearly not LISP. I also suggest you may find this discussion easier on the R-dev mailing list where lots of R people will be interested to hear from you.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I just want to merely write out what will be a pitfall for others.