# Confused by the behavior of closure

Tags: r

The following simplified version of my program captures the confusion.

I am trying to create a set of functions *f1, f2, ..., fK, ..., fn* defined as *fK(x) = print(K + x)*. For this, I created the function factory:

```
factory = function (K) {
    function (x) print(K + x)
}
```

And use it to create 5 functions: `funcs = sapply(1:5, factory)`

I call them one by one, for the same value: *x = 10*

```
callOnef = function (f, x) f(x)
sapply(funcs, callOnef, 10)
```

I expected the output to be (one per line) *11 12 13 14 15*, but I instead got (one per line) *15 15 15 15 15* **and** on the 6th line, a row of five *15* 's.

When I inserted a `print(K)` in the definition of `factory`, the output changed to (one per line) *11 12 13 14 15* **and** on the 6th line, a row of *11 12 13 14 15*. (Ignoring the output of print(K) itself, that preceded the 6 lines)

This confused me a lot. I found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168487/accumulating-functions-and-closures-in-r) where there's a suggestion to use `force`.

So, I replaced `print(K)` with `force(K)`:

```
factory = function (K) {
    force(K)
    function (x) print(K + x)
}
```

The output is now (one per line) *11 12 13 14 15* **and** on the 6th line, a row of *11 12 13 14 15*.

Questions:

1. Why does the evaluation of K (like in my case through `print(K)` or `force(K)`,) change the behavior of the closure?
2. Why the 6th line? It looks identical to the output of print(K + 10) **if** K was a *vector* equal to *1:5*.

Comment: This is partially a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15742177/269476. The second part is due to the fact that `sapply` returns and prints (if used interactively) the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This strange behavior is a consequence of R's lazy evaluation.  R doesn't evaluate the parameters to a function until it needs to.  Instead it creates a promise object, which consists of a expression and an environment.

You can see what is happening more clearly in this code:

```
> factory = function (K) {
+     function (x) {
+         print(K + x)
+     }
+ }
> funcs<-list()
> for(i in 1:5)
+     funcs[[i]]<-factory({cat("evaluating K:",i,"\n"); i})
>
```

Nothing was printed out, meaning that the arguments to the `factory` calls have not been evaluated yet.  They are still bound to the promise of evaluating `{cat("evaluating K:",i,"\n"); i}` in the global environment.  Since `i` now is equal to `5`, then we get this behavior:

```
> funcs[[1]](10)
evaluating K: 5 
[1] 15
```

If we change `i` in the global environment, it will affect the still unevaluated promises, but not the promises which have already been resolved:

```
> i<-4
> funcs[[2]](10)
evaluating K: 4 
[1] 14
> funcs[[1]](10)
[1] 15
```

The reason `force` changes this behavior is because `force` forces a promise to be evaluated on the spot, so the promise immediately becomes a value.

As for the second part of your question, the 6'th row is simply the output of `sapply`, which concatenates together the results of all the expressions.

Comment: Thanks for this very clear explanation! I wonder why this important consequence of lazy evaluation isn't mentioned in the [R intro](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html). It would be very helpful for newbies :)

Comment: @Anant Yes, the R documentation can be less than ideal sometimes.  Promises and lazy evaluation are mentioned in the R language definition though: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Promise-objects